# How to send "delayed" sms?

Tags: iphone, applications, sms

Instead of sending an SMS *right now*, I would like to send a "delayed" SMS. For example, delay it by 45 minutes, or 60 minutes, etc.

Is there any way to do it?

I have tried the apps [txtot](http://www.txtot.com/), [FutureText](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/futuretext/id576596693?mt=8), and [SMS Scheduler](https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/sms-scheduler/id646308617?mt=8), but they don't work. The default iPhone "Messages" app cannot receive SMSes sent by these apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to jailbreak your iPhone, I can strongly suggest [biteSMS](http://bitesms.com/). It supports schedules texting [among many other things](http://bitesms.com/main/more_features). A killer app!

[image]

Comment: This application no longer appears to exist -- the domain is dead, and the associated Twitter account hasn't been updated since 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Without jailbreak what you ask isn't possible. Third party Apps from the App Store can't access the SMS service.

With a jailbreak there seems to be apps on the Cydia Store that have this function. Like **Future SMS**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the app called SMS Auto Sender. I tried it in US and Canada and works well. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/auto-sender/id1375015129?mt=8

Answer (score -1):

you should try [txtot+](https://itunes.apple.com/app/txtot+-send-sms-later/id660633414?mt=8) it works, and it free to try!

Comment: It doesn't work. The default iPhone "Messages" app cannot receive SMSes sent by these apps.

Comment: I know for sure it work in Europe and i believe it also works in Singapore you can contact txtot+ support team if you can't send scheduled sms, they will help you

Comment: hmm I've tried many times and it never worked. What steps did you take to send the delayed SMS?

Answer (score -1):

The [RemindMe](http://www.remindme.ie) service offers a text scheduler that does what you need:

> Create SMS appointment reminders for specific events at a date and time specified by you. You can schedule text messages as a once off reminder or for recurring events.

Comment: That's true, but it somewhat clunky–it's designed as a calendar app, not as an automated SMS service.

Answer (score -2):

Try Joopz.com, works great and you don't have to jail break your phone.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant -- Joopz is a CRM system intended for use by businesses, not by end-users.

Answer (score -2):

I found this works, at least at my iPhone 8.
https://www.freeramble.com/sms.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link is often not the best approach as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of why FreeRamble meets the needs of the asker?

Comment: If you are the developer of this app, or in any way benefit from the sale of this app, you should state this explicitly in your answer.